# Different ComboBox values in DataGridView in different rows

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

```
    private void dgv_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int MaxRows = dgv.Rows.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < MaxRows-1; i++)
        {                
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT CAST(originalPrice * " + (1.00 + (float.Parse(txtMarkUp.Text) / 100.00)).ToString() + " * " + (1.00 + (float.Parse(dgv.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString()) / 100.00)).ToString() + " AS decimal (8,2)) AS sellingPrice FROM Warehouse WHERE barcode = '" + Convert.ToString(dgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value) + "'", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn sellingPrice = dgv.Columns["sellingPrice"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;

            sellingPrice.DataSource = dt;
            sellingPrice.ValueMember = "sellingPrice";
            sellingPrice.DisplayMember = "sellingPrice";

            dgv.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(0);
            dgv.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString(); //percent of tax for that category of product
        }
    }
```

This code is working perfectly but only for one values in combobox... I need different values in different rows for the combobox. How can I do that?
In example when in column 2 product is changed, I need it to change the values of column 5 which is combobox with the selling prices.
Any help would be appreciated, I have almost no solution for this in my mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure what you want assuming that you want to bind different values row wise for the combobox column
In that Case if you can determine the condition row wise use this

```
(dgv.Rows[i].Cells[5] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).DataSource = dt;
(dgv.Rows[i].Cells[5] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).ValueMember = "sellingPrice";
(dgv.Rows[i].Cells[5] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).DisplayMember = "sellingPrice";
```

This will set the DataSource for that particular cell instead of the Column which you are currently doing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, and what I mistaked.. thanks a lot for giving me the direction.
p.s. This is still giving me an error, maybe because datamember and valuemember aren't set. How can I set them to that cell?

Comment: It says DataGridViewComboBoxCell value isn't valid.

Comment: Edited for setting up the members.

Comment: Thanks, it's working, now I'm going to correct the rest of the code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle [`CellParsing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellparsing.aspx) event of you datagridview and when the product cell is changed and the user navigates to another cell, populate the combo box with your desired results.

Comment: CellEndEdit is almost the same, so I think it won't make a big difference, any way thanks for the reply.

Comment: You can use the e.value from `cellparsing` event to find out which product has been selected and do the db request based on it and then bind the combobox of that row to the newly fetched result. I can't test it now but I think it should work.